# React - .map not returning items in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to React and have an issue with my .map function:

I have a component with the following render function:

```
render() {
    return <div className="sidenav-cont"><ul className="top-level-menu">
            {
                this.props.loadSidenavItems.map((menuItem) => {
                    console.log(menuItem.parentCat)
                return              
                    (
                    <li key={menuItem.catId}>
                        <a href="#">{menuItem.parentCat}</a>
                    </li>
                    )
                })
            }

    </ul>
</div>
    }
```

This is the object i'm trying to map:

```
export default 
     [
            {
            catId:"parMenu1",
            parentCat:"Genres",
        },
        {
            catId:"parMenu2",
            parentCat:"Sound Type",
        },
    ]
```

My console log returns the two values I want which is great but my no list items get rendered to the DOM. Not sure where i've gone wrong here?

Comment: maybe the newline directly after the `return` (there can be some side effects if a newline is before any other statements)

Comment: @Icepickle is right, https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/60086/

Comment: your answer is correct icpickle!

Comment: You are welcome, I added a bit more info in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit stupid, but `return` has to be followed by a statement or many javascript engines will simply assume you forgot a `;`

See following example where you would expect twice hello world, but get `undefined` once

A better explanation is given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> **Automatic Semicolon Insertion**
>   The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression.

```js
function testFunctionIncorrect() {
  return
    "hello world";
}

function testFunctionCorrect() {
  return "hello " + 
    "world";
}

console.log( testFunctionIncorrect() );
console.log( testFunctionCorrect() );
```